# mysql build index on a integer with limited values

Tags: mysql, indexing

suppose I have an integer in a mysql innodb table, in reality it can only be 0 or 1, would building an index on it makes any reasonable difference on the performance?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql indexing performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705971/mysql-indexing-performance)

Answer (score 0):

you should really look at [mysql indexing performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705971/mysql-indexing-performance)

also, if you have such column - for performance reasons it is better to have 2 tables sometimes, consider this option